# how to get value of field with space in xsl file

Tags: xslt, sharepoint-2013

Creating an ItemStyle XSL file for content query Webpart, i want to get value from the **Pages** library that inherits from **Article Pages**. this is OK with title or fields with no space. However, i seems not to work with field containing space, its display name is Article Date. I did try the following code:

```
   <xsl:value-of select="@Article&#160;Date" />
```

Could you tell me, how could i do in such case? should i call external name of this field inside xsl file, like  or other ways?

Comment: Attribute names cannot contain spaces. Therefore, `Article Date` cannot be a valid attribute name in a well-formed XML document. Can you show your XML source?

Comment: You don't provide enough information about the problem to enable any intelligent answers.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/sharepoint-internal-field-names/), the internal name for "Article Date" is `ArticleStartDate`.  Try using that instead, and you may have more success.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@ArticleStartDate" />
```